# UI for a sign-in screen which allows to log in with a username or phone number

Tags: login, password, username, phone-numbers

I have a sign-in screen which allows a user to log in with a username or a phone number.

As the phone number must be in an "international" format, it confuses users, some of them fail to sign in.

To fix that issue, I am thinking using a dropdown with phone prefix ( +33, +44 ), but in that case it can be confusing the user who want to enter his username.

Should I add a different field for username?

Comment: Are you using the same textfield for both? If yes, I would go for a 2 separate textfields, better to not confuse the user.

Comment: If this is a mobile only application, I will suggest to stick to just phone number to log in.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this sounds like two options that are different enough to be separated visually.

The best experience would probably be that it recognizes the number no matter the format they use when entering. Then the one box would suffice. But I understand that the format recognition would be too hard to implement. I even noticed that many big operators do not even allow it; out of the three biggest Scandinavian operators, two just accept username or email, and the third even failed with an error message when using a bad number.

Back to your case: You do not necessarily have to put them in the same screen:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9vl0o.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Another example with multiple log in methods, is using tabs. Not my preferred option, but common, so here is an example from a bank:

[image]

Comment: I like this idea. This allows for less confusion and allows users who are aiming for a certain login can find it immediately through different options.

Answer (score 0):

Separate fields for different content is a good solution. Otherwise one input field has two modes: username entering and phone number entering with its constraints. The content types is too different.

Also some users don't know theirs' country code, so it's good to let them choose country instead of its' code.

Answer (score 0):

don't make it too hard for your user: you can guess the prefix based on their location, if they enter a number as a first entry, they most likely will enter a phone number. Pop up the pre fix. If they enter a letter, they will 100% enter an email. Do nothing. (in the textfield)

Answer (score 0):

You can have one "username" text input, whether it's a phone number with a country prefix or not, or an actual username or an email address, should be irrelevant, cater for all the cases that the user can enter it in behind the scenes and log them in if one is a match. Facebook does it so well, you can login with

1. Phone number (international and local format)
2. Username
3. E-mail address